# How can I test a field for a specific character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do I determine if a SQL Server 2012 field contains a specific character or string without using fulltext commands using a select?

Comment: `select * from table where column1_name like '%vijjuu%'` ??

Comment: give example for specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CHARINDEX() function if you just wanted to see if the string or character exists in the input rather than selecting the whole row:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(50)
SET @string = 'string to search'

SELECT CHARINDEX('to',@string)
```

This code would return 8 (the start position of the string you searched for), if you searched for something that didn't exist, it would return 0, so you could determine if a string existed by looking for a return integer greater than 0.